# How can I hide a li using jquery? hide() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is the html code

```
<button value="{store name}" type="button" id="store_name">{store name}</button>
<ul>
    <li id="#store_name_li">Add your brand name. <a>{store name}</a></li>
</ul>
```

here is the Jquery

```
$('#store_name').on('click', function () {
    $('#store_name_li').hide(); // not working
    var stuff = $(this).val();
    $('.emojionearea-editor').append(stuff); // working
});
```

what is the problem here?

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: No.............

Comment: ```$('#store_name_li').css('display','none');```  it also didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change,

```
 <li id="#store_name_li">Add your brand name. <a>{store name}</a></li>
```

**to**:

```
 <li id="store_name_li">Add your brand name. <a>{store name}</a></li>
```

Remove **#** from `id="#store_name_li"`.

Working snippet as follows,

```js
$('#store_name').on('click', function () {
    $('#store_name_li').hide(); // not working
    var stuff = $(this).val();
    $('.emojionearea-editor').append(stuff); // working
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="{store name}" type="button" id="store_name">{store name}</button>
<ul>
    <li id="store_name_li">Add your brand name. <a>{store name}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was my mistake that I didn't found. :(

Comment: @tariqulanik, Typo's are unavoidable.. Glad to help you..